# Very weird redirection behavior

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, redirect, io-redirection

I execute a program which print some texts. I redirect the texts to file by using `>` but I cannot see any texts on the file. For example, if the program prints "Hello" I can see the result on the shell:

```
$ ./a.out arg
Hello
```

But after I redirect I cannot get any message hello on shell as well as the redirected file.

```
$ ./a.out arg > log.txt
(print nothing)

$ cat log.txt
(print nothing)
```

I have no idea what's going on. Is there someone who knows what's happening here? Or is there someone who suffered similar situation?

OS: Ubuntu 14.10, x86_64 arch, and the program is really `chromium-browser` rather than `./a.out`. I edited its JavaScript engine (v8, which is included in `chromium-browser`) and I tried to print some logs with lots of texts. I tried to save it by redirection but it doesn't work.

Surely I checked whether `>` symbol work or not. It works as expected on other programs like `echo`, `ls`, and so on.

```
$ echo hello > hello.txt
$ cat hello.txt
hello
```

How can the messages just go away? I think it should be printed on `stdout` (or `stderr`) or file. But it just goes away when I use `>` symbol.

Comment: With it being Chrome, I would expect there to be a control parameter that allows you to specify where the diagnostics are written.  However, I don't know where to find it or what it is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is somewhat common for programs to check `isatty(stdout)` and display different output based on whether stdout is connected to a terminal or not. For example, `ls` will display file names in a tabular format if output is to a terminal, but display them strictly one per line otherwise. It does this to make it easy to parse its output when it's part of a pipeline.

Not having looked at Chrome's source code myself, this is speculation, but it's possible Chrome is performing this sort of check and changing its output based on where stdout is redirected to.

Comment: A reasonable way to test this is: `./a.out | cat`

Answer (score -1):

Try to use "2>" which should redirect stderr to file

Or you can also try to use "&>" which should redirect everything (stderr and stdout)

See more at http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html

Comment: Not my down-vote, but the down-voter probably considers that although the information is technically accurate in itself, it is not relevant to solving the issue in the question.

Comment: Also not my down-vote, and although the question is tagged 'linux' and 'shell', it is not valid to assume bash.  Although `&>` redirects both streams in bash, it is not valid syntax in all shells.  (eg, dash will treat `cmd &> file` as two commands, running `cmd` in the background and then truncating `file`.  One could argue that bash's behavior is in direct violation of the shell standard.